# angular filter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to make filter through mass of objects.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.contact">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.company_phone">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.address">
<div class="matrix_container">
<div class="matrix">

    <div ng-repeat="row in search_result track by $index | filter:search">
        <div class="properties">{{row.name}}</div>
        <div class="properties">{{row.contact}}</div>
        <div class="properties">{{row.company_phone}}</div>
        <div class="properties">{{row.address}}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

There is a message about a mistake

> Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/filter/notarray?p0=0

typeof search_result is obejct, but as I know in js object=array, no?

console.log(search_result)

[image]

Comment: error link says ..`This error occurs when filter is not used with an array:`, so confirm `search_result` is array ?

Comment: yep, array of objects.

Comment: post `search_result ` in qstn too.

Comment: @anoop already done)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`track by $index` should be applied at the last, So it should be like:

```
ng-repeat="row in search_result | filter:search track by $index"
```

See this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sssfxtd4/)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!)